# Javascript Draw line with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, line

Please see my code here http://jsbin.com/ijoxa3/edit

```
var drawHorizondalLine = function(x1,y1,x2,y2, color) {

          var width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
          var posX  = (x1 > x2) ? x1 : x2;
          var id ='c_'+new Date().getTime()
          var line = "<div id='"+id+"'class='line'>&nbsp;</div>";

          $('body').append(line);

          $('#'+id).css({
            left: posX,
            top: y1,
            width: width,
            position:'absolute',
            backgroundColor: color
          });

};


$(document).ready(function() {
  drawHorizondalLine(0, 10, 200, 10, '#a00');
  drawHorizondalLine(0, 50, 100, 50, '#0a0');
});
<style>

.line{
    padding;1px;
  } 
</style>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>​
```

The function call `drawHorizondalLine(0, 10, 200, 10, '#a00');` is suppose to draw a line form the top left corner of the page, 100px in length, but the the line appear to start from the last div of the body.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Just tested in FF 3.6 and looks working fine.

Comment: @Artem Barger, I just edited the question, Please see the HTML part too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var posX  = (x1 > x2) ? x1 : x2;
```

should be

```
var posX  = (x1 < x2) ? x1 : x2;
```

Working demo is [here](http://jsbin.com/enime3/edit)